# Downloading large images > 1 GB asynchronously for Windows 8 Apps

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have a requirement where you need to download multiple images using Web Services or WCF Rest to Windows 8 App asynchronously. What is the best way of doing this by keeping the UI very responsive. For e.g. if a user selects an item, it can contain 4 images of very large size. How to download and display large images, any good solution for this? 
Only Solution seems to be Background Transfer with threads. Any other good design technique for this

Comment: Is BITS available to Windows 8 Apps by chance?

Comment: Just starting to solution, so have not tried anything